# Jenkins is not opening in browser only in my laptop?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

From two days I am facing this problem. Till 2 days before Jenkins.... worked without any error in my laptop. My Jenkins server is in AWS EC2 (Amazon Linux). All my deployments are also there in Jenkins.

The problem is …. it is not loading in the browser only in my laptop but when i checked in other's laptop it is working fine.

How to solve this solution ?

Comment: Both laptops are in same network? same internet connection?

Comment: Yes bro. in my organization only. in my co employee's laptop it is browsing but in my laptop it is not browsing from 2 days

Comment: Bro just now i figured out. with organization's wifi it is not loading but when i tried with my mobile hotspot jenkins is working. How to solve this ?

Comment: What happens instead when you try to load that page? Looks like a pure networking issue to me, not related to programming?

Comment: @SettibathulaManiGopalNaidu Your Org WIFI blocks access for AWS EC2 somehow. Best way would be to contact Org IT support. Because to troubleshoot this, you have to share host entries and network table details here, that will break ORG policies.

Comment: @NicoHaase it is showing "can't reach this page" when loading with company's wife and with my mobile hotspot jenkins is loading fine

Comment: @c.sankhala i understood but what if we don't have IT support here ?

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve that? How is this related to programming itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase i didn't said this is related to programming

Comment: Then please move your question to another page that is more suitable, like https://superuser.com/ - StackOverflow's main focus are programming-related questions

Comment: any new software installed after it worked last? like docker or network related software?